# My email sender route doesn't work properly

Tags: php, email, laravel, error-handling, laravel-5

Hello I have a problem with my email sender route that I have set up.

I have a form where you can put in your name and email and a message. Then when I submit the form, I send the user to the email sender route which goes to a controller that handles everything, but it doesn't even get to that controller.

Below is the error message and the form code:

[image: Route error after submit form]

[image: Form]

Here are the route definitions:

```
Route::get('/', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@home'
]);

Route::get('/home', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@home'
]);

Route::get('/about', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@about'
]);

Route::get('/contact', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@contact'
]);

Route::get('/gallery', [
    'as' => 'home',
    'uses' => 'HomeController@gallery'
]);

Route::get('/contact/email', [
    'as' => 'send',
    'uses' => 'EmailController@sendmail'
]);
```

If you guys could help me get to the controller, I can handle the rest from there.

Answer (score 0):

Your route method is `GET` but you're form method is `POST`, that's the reason you're gettting the `MethodNotAllowedException`. You need to change the route to this:

```
Route::post('/contact/email', [
    'as' => 'send',
    'uses' => 'EmailController@sendmail'
]);
```

Comment: Im so sorry, i feel really stupid now... but after all im pretty new to laravel but Thank you !